# Apache Spark job calling java program and showing different behavior in RDD and Dataframe

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

This is my spark program which is getting executed in yarn cluster environment.

```
// Making a call to java program from spark scala program
val affiliationRowRDD = affiliationDistinctRowRDD.map(a =>Row.fromSeq(
      datavolveFromJavaJob.callDatavolveFromJavaJob(a.toString()).split(",").toSeq
    ))


//printing  count and records of rdd - This is printing correctly all 32 fields in each record  
affiliationRowRDD.take(10).foreach(println)
affiliationRowRDD.take(10).foreach { x => println(x) }
affiliationRowRDD.collect().foreach { x => println(x)}
affiliationRowRDD.collect().foreach ( x => println(x) )

// creating dataframe by applying/providing schema  
val affiliationCombinedDF =      hiveContext.createDataFrame(affiliationRowRDD, prefinal_affiliation_schema)


//this DF is printing different records than what was printed from RDD. 
affiliationCombinedDF.printSchema()
affiliationCombinedDF.show(5)

// saving in Hive           
affiliationCombinedDF.saveAsTable("d_affiliation_orc_delete", SaveMode.Append) //enter code here
```

Issue is - In above code 
RDD print correct response received from Java call/method every time.
But after creating DataFrame, when I printed DataFrame contents I see different field data than what was printed from RDD previously.
Java program throws the error if something goes wrong.  And I am seeing this errors are getting printed from DataFrame.

Is this Java program getting called multiple times on cluster from different servers from where Spark distributed job executing? 
Is it making one more call to Java program/method during DataFrame creation. 
- Don't think so but not able to understand why this is happening.

Any idea why this kind of behavior is occurring on cluster environment.

Comment: Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work so it can be improved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this Java program getting called multiple times on cluster from different servers from where Spark distributed job executing?

Yes it is. Since it is executed inside `map` it happens in parallel on the workers.

> Is it making one more call to Java program/method during DataFrame creation

It is called at least once per element of the `affiliationDistinctRowRDD`. It can be called more than once if a given partition has to be recomputed.

If `affiliationRowRDD` is not cached then it happens each time* you execute an action that depends on it. Even if data is cached it is still can be automatically removed from cache and recomputed later.

> Java program throws the error if something goes wrong. And I am seeing this errors are getting printed from DataFrame.

Exception handling is your responsibility. There is no difference between DataFrame and RDD API here. If call to the external API may fail (when it is not the case?) then it should be handled by `callDatavolveFromJavaJob` function.

---

* There can be some special cases when there is shuffling involved.